# KnockoutJS - disable binding - how to disable child elements when parent has value

Tags: knockout.js

I've written a jsfiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish below. Have a requirement when a value is entered in the parent (excursion) pay amount input, the child (charge) pay amounts should be disabled. And vice versa, when a pay amount is entered into either child (charge) pay amount input, the parent disables. I've think I have it working perfectly for the parent - it disables both child inputs - but when entering a value in the second charge input, it doesn't disable the parent. It's also hardcoded, so I'm needing help with this part:

```
charges()[0].payAmount() != '' || charges()[0].payAmount() != 0
```

I've seen this - [Knockoutjs Update child when parent's observable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782800/knockoutjs-update-child-when-parents-observable-changes) - to add a subscriber, but I don't think I can still access/disable the children from there. Or maybe I can, with jQuery? I've also seen this - [Is there any way to disable a bunch of form elements at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646823/is-there-any-way-to-disable-a-bunch-of-form-elements-at-once) - using a binding handler to potentially handle the disabling of the $parent maybe when entering a value in the children's inputs. Seems complicated though. I noticed that in the ko [enable binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) that you can pass an abitrary expression, but you can't seem to pass in any parameters, like the current object. And, on the function signature, if I add excursion as an argument, I've verified it's undefined. Here's a function I had tried to attach to the disable binding on the parent, to no avail, as encounter is undefined:

```
function hasChildEntries(encounter) {
    ko.utils.arrayFirst(encounter.charges(), function (charge) {
        console.log(charge + ', ' + charge.payAmount() + '...');
        if (charge.payAmount() != '' || charge.payAmount() != 0)
            return true;
    });
    return false;
};
```

view:

```
<div>
    <ul class="payments">
    <!-- ko foreach: excursions -->
    <li class="payments">
        <div class="payments">
        <a href='#' class="expand glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" style="color:grey"></a>
        <a href='#' class="collapse glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" style="color:grey"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="payments" data-bind="text: 'Excursion ID: ' + id + '&nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Amount: '"></div>
        <input class="payments" data-bind="
            textInput: payAmount,
            valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
            disable: charges()[0].payAmount() != '' || charges()[0].payAmount() != 0" />
        <ul class="payments bullet">
        <!-- ko foreach: charges -->
        <li class="payments">
            <div class="payments" data-bind="text: name + '&nbsp;&nbsp;Pay Amount: '"></div>
            <input class="payments" data-bind="
                textInput: payAmount,
                valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
                disable: $parent.payAmount() != '' || $parent.payAmount() != 0" />
        </li>
        <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

view model/javascript:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.excursions = ko.observableArray().extend({ rateLimit: 0 });

    function Excursion(id, name, chgAmount, payAmount, charges) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.chgAmount = chgAmount;
    this.payAmount = ko.observable('');
    this.charges = ko.observableArray(charges).extend({ rateLimit: 0 });
    };

    function Charge(id, name, date, chgAmount, payAmount) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
    this.chgAmount = chgAmount;
    this.payAmount = ko.observable('');
    };

    self.excursions.push(new Excursion('1234', 'Excursion 1', 90.00, 0, undefined));
    ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.excursions(), function (excursion) {
    if (excursion.id = '1234') {
        excursion.charges.push(new Charge(1, 'Trunk Bay', '02/10/2015', 50.00, 0));
        excursion.charges.push(new Charge(2, 'Cinnamon Bay', '02/10/2015', 40.00, 0));
    }
    });
    self.excursions.push(new Excursion('1235', 'Excursion 2', 80.00, 0, undefined));
    ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.excursions(),  function (excursion) {
    if (excursion.id == '1235')
        excursion.charges.push(new Charge(3, 'Coral Bay', '02/11/2015', 80.00, 0));
    });
}

var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$(".expand").click(function () { 
    $(this).toggle(); 
    $(this).next().toggle(); 
    $(this).parent().parent().children().last().toggle();
}); 
$(".collapse").click(function () { 
    $(this).toggle(); 
    $(this).prev().toggle(); 
    $(this).parent().parent().children().last().toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
.altRow:nth-child(even) td { background-color: #D8D8D8; }
ul.payments { list-style:none; float:left; width:100% }
li.payments { padding-top:10px; float:left; width:100% }
div.payments { float:left }
.expand { width:15px;height:15px; }
.collapse { width:15px;height:15px;display:none }
ul.payments.bullet {list-style-type: disc;}
input.payments { width:80px;height:20px; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfortner/8j8k7h1c/30/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a computed to your excursion model:

```
this.hasCharges = ko.computed(function() {
  for(var i = 0, len = charges().length; i < len; i++ ) {
    if( charges()[i].payAmount() ) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

and then in your markup, replace

```
disable: charges()[0].payAmount() != '' || charges()[0].payAmount() != 0"
```

with

```
disable: hasCharges
```

This will disable the parent no matter how many children it has

edit: a fiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/8j8k7h1c/33/

try to avoid using 'this' in your functions, scoping gets messed up. I used

```
var self = this;
```

to keep the charges observable accessible by the computed function.

Comment: Yeah, perfect. I had read that you should use computed functions to control this, but didn't realize you had to attach it to the function so the instance of that parent/child knew each other. Superb - thanks a lot! Good point on using self in functions - I've seen that, but have not been doing it. Still somewhat new to ko...

Comment: Oh, and nice update to just using if( charges()[i].payAmount() ) {, instead of checking for != '' or != 0, so it's checking for a "truthy" expression. Nice change.

Comment: yay for truthiness. it would also catch null/undefined if you didn't initialize your observable